# How to change styles for all numbers in string in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, numbers, styles, superscript

How to change styles for all numbers in strings (from strings.xml) to (small) and (subscript) and (color.blue)? and where put that in recyclerView adapter (all strings in Array)?

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kotlin, use regex to replace all the numbers with HTML formatting.

```kotlin
var text = "This is an example of text[1] formatting."
"\\[[0-9]+\\]".toRegex().findAll(text)
    .flatMap { it.groupValues }
    .forEach {
        val num = it.drop(1).dropLast(1)
        text = text.replace(it, "<sup>[$num]</sup>")
    }
```

Then use `tvMyTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text))`

Comment: Thank you for reply. I think you need to try Kotlin first, because html in (Html.fromHtml(html)) unknown and need to be html.toString() and result is = (kotlin.Unit).

Comment: Thanks. My mistake. I've changed the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Now it worked, but how it work with Hindi numbers? and what about other style (color and small)? can we use SpannableString?

Comment: For Hindi, you have to map the `num` variable into Hindi alphabet equivalent. One quick way is `num.toCharArray().map{ c -> when(c) { /*1 -> १...*/ }}.joinToString("")`

Comment: For colors, just use `"<sup><font color="blue">[$num]</font></sup>"`. Of course, you can use `SpannableString`, but that's another topic. Kindly mark the answer as solution, if it worked for you.

Comment: Thank You a lot, if I need just numbers without [ ], what can I remove from \\[[0-9]+\\]?
and I added this:
num.toCharArray().map { c ->
                    when (c) {
                        '0' -> '٠' ...
                        else -> '٩'
                    }}.joinToString("")
but it is not work. any help?